# How to apply color when append html element in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my HTML code.

```js
$('.clickhere').click(function (){
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    $('.list').append('<p class="clicknow">prasnaga</p>');
  }
});

$('.clicknow').click(function (){
  $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list"> </div>
<a class="clickhere">clickhere</a>
```

This is way I apply style using jQuery

`$(this).css('color','red');`

What I want is to click `clicknow` word should apply style but not apply my current code can you help me to solve this problem?

[Here is code](https://jsfiddle.net/prasangakarunanayake/ajcxw6zm/2/)

Comment: use event delegation.. use `.on()`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ajcxw6zm/3/

Comment: Thank! your support @satpal